# error: column "age" does not exist [node + pg + postgres]

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Hi i'm trying to do an INSERT to my database using pg in node.js but i've got one 
error: column "age" does not exist.

this is my code:

```
    app.post('/saving', function(req, res){
  var age = req.param('Age');
  var gender = req.param('gender');
  //res.send(age + gender)
  pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
    if(err) {
      return res.send('error')
    }
    client.query('INSERT INTO  public.attack (age, gender) VALUES (age , gender)')

    done()
  })
})
```

here my db:

```
    test=# \d attack;
                              Table "public.attack"
 Column |       Type        |                      Modifiers                      
--------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 age    | integer           | 
 gender | character varying | 
 id     | integer           | not null default nextval('attack_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "attack_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO public.attack (age, gender) VALUES (age, gender)` is *exactly* what your database will see, since it doesn't know anything about what variables you have in your JavaScript.

Comment: ok problem solved but now when i post the browser still pending (infinite).

Comment: If you open a new question with the details of your code and what's happening, the SO (StackOverflow) community would love to help you out!

Answer (score 2):

`age` and `gender` inside `VALUES (age, gender)` will not be defined, as far as postgres is concerned. You'll want to use a [prepared statement](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Prepared-Statements#parameterized-queries) (or a parameterized query, more specifically) in this case to pass variables along with the query.

This is probably similar to the code you'll want, I believe:

```
let sql = 'INSERT INTO public.attack (age, gender) VALUES ($1, $2)';
let params = [ age, gender ];
client.query(sql, params, function(err) {
  // make sure you handle errors from here as well,
  // including signaling `res` and `done`
});
```

Comment: Specifically, do you mean that `age` and `gender` won't be interpolated into the request?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by interpolated - Yes, you have to make sure you provide the values directly, since postgres has no idea what's in the javascript code. I would strongly suggest using parameterized queries. I've updated to include an example as well as the link to the postgres driver documentation.

Comment: Personally, I'm not familiar with Node.js and DBs, but yeah, that's basically what I mean.